# invalid character in identifier (urls.py, line 5) in Django

Tags: python, django, django-urls

This is first time I am learning Django and getting the following error.

invalid character in identifier (urls.py, line 5) in Django
This error is occuring from my application urls.py

This is how my app urls.py looks like:

```
from django.conf.urls import *

from maasapp import *

urlpatterns = [url(r’^home/’,'maasapp.views.home',name='home'),]
```

Please can someone help me...

Comment: I suggest that you use something similar to this: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` to declare what kind of encoding you're using. That won't solve your issue since you're using the wrong characters for strings, but if you use special characters in your files, you will need something like that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are putting the wrong quotes. Replace:

```
r’^home/’
```

with:

```
r'^home/'
```

Comment: Dammit, beat me to it ;) - This answer should be accepted by OP.

Comment: Thanks, but I removed my answer, no need to have two exact answers here :)